# Need help to convert array into string in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am using PasswordHash.php from Openwall to hash passwords. Method CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash) should compare user entered password with hashed password in my database. This method only accepts arguments as string. I am having troubles to convert arrays into string. I fetched stored hash array from database and imploded it. For some reason Checkpassword method still returns false. Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Login.php code:

```
<?php 
require 'PasswordHash.php';
// Base-2 logarithm of the iteration count used for password stretching
$hash_cost_log2 = 8;
// Do we require the hashes to be portable to older systems (less secure)?
$hash_portable = FALSE;

$hasher = new PasswordHash($hash_cost_log2, $hash_portable);


$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

include ('config.php');

function fail($pub, $pvt = '') {
$msg = $pub;
if ($pvt !== '')
    $msg .= ": $pvt";
exit("An error occurred ($msg).\n");
 }


$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
fail('MySQL connect', mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE user = '$user'";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 1){
$stored_hash = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$stored_hash_ = implode("", $stored_hash);

$check  = $hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $stored_hash_);

if($check) {
    echo "Correct";
} else {
    echo "Wrong pw";
}

} else {

    echo "Error";
}

$db->close();

?>
```

PasswordHash.php - https://github.com/alexdunae/simplelogin-secure/blob/master/phpass-0.1/PasswordHash.php (http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `print_r($stored_hash_);`, currently it will return something similar to this:

```
<pre>
Array [
    ['password_field_name_here'] => 'userpassword123'
]
</pre>
```

Fix this by looping through the array like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 1){

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $stored_hash = $row['password_field_name_here'];
}

$stored_hash_ = implode("", $stored_hash);

$check  = $hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $stored_hash_);

if($check) {
    echo "Correct";
} else {
    echo "Wrong pw";
}
```

The `$stored_hash_` will now be, for example; 'userpassword123'

Comment: Methods print_r($pass); print_($stored_hash_); gave me the following output:  asd $2a$08$SPaSC5t60XSHiwMcjLw7...                                                                                             Stored hash is exactly the same I have in my database. I don't understand the looping part where you give row field argument. Stored hash is hashed password in my database that I first need to select with sql.

Comment: Used $result->fetch_row(); instead mysqli_fetch_array($result); and it fixed the problem. Solved.